# Dynamic connection string for entity framework code first for multiple database providers at runtime EF6 ( mssql, mysql, oracle )

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to connect multiple database provider using entity framework code first model, by generating connection string dynamically. But it's not working as expected.

Here is code to review :

```
 switch (providerName)
        {
            case "System.Data.SqlClient":
                entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
                entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;
                //ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mssql"].ConnectionString
                break;
            case "MySql.Data.MySqlClient":
                entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
                entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;
                //ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        switch (providerName)
        {
            case "System.Data.SqlClient":
                conn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString)
                {

                    UserID = databaseUserId,
                    Password = databasePassword,
                    DataSource = serverName,
                    IntegratedSecurity = false,
                    InitialCatalog = databaseName

                }.ConnectionString;

                break;
            case "MySql.Data.MySqlClient":
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString)
                {
                    Server = serverName,
                    UserID = databaseUserId,
                    Password = databasePassword,
                    Database = databaseName,
                    PersistSecurityInfo = true

                }.ConnectionString;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Web.config

`<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>`

```
 <DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

DbContext constructor

```
  ` public partial class ModelCodeFist : DbContext
{
    public ModelCodeFist(string connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
    }
}
```

`

**Also how can i change default provider at runtime, as EF takes sql connector as defaultConnectionFactory**

Dynamically **connecting to mssql is working**, but for **mysql it's generating error** because the **default connector is still sqlclient**, please check image below :
[image]

Let me know, if i missed something 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your own ProviderFactory implementing IDbConnectionFactory

```
public class MyProviderFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{    
    public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        if ("mySqlName".equals(nameOrConnectionString))
        {
            return new MySqlConnection("<Connection String>");
        }
        else 
        {
            return new SqlConnection("<Connection String>");
        }
    }
}
```

Then set this in your app.config as the DefaultConnectionFactory

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MyAssmebly.MyProviderFactory, MyAssmebly">
  <parameters>
```

Not tested code, certainly not performance tested!